# Couldn't install p5 library for python 3.11.5 because it failed to build wheel for Pillow and PyOpenGL-accelerate

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll

Here is the commands I used in he command prompt and the output it gave:

```
      src\wrapper.c(28232): error C2037: left of 'f_lineno' specifies undefined struct/union '_frame'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyOpenGL-accelerate
Failed to build Pillow PyOpenGL-accelerate
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, PyOpenGL-accelerate, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

already tried to install it using python directly in the command prompt, if u could help in any way I would be very thankful